# How does the vscode extension bring a binary program

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

```ts
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const umlgen = execFile(binpath, args, { cwd: workingPath });
umlgen.stdout.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});
let errMessage: string = "";
umlgen.stderr.on('data', (data: Uint8Array) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

umlgen.on('close', (code: number) => {
  console.log(`close: ${code}`);
});
```

I use child_process to run binary program in my workplace. The path can be found when the program is debugged, but it cannot be found after packaging.

```
.
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── README.md
├── node_modules
├── out
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
├── tsconfig.json
├── umlgen
└── vsc-extension-quickstart.md
```

umlgen is binary program.
src is code of vscode extension.

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-acquire-dependencies-for-visual-studio-code-extensions-9ca828cb168d

Comment: I prefer to put the program directly in the extension, so that no additional operations are required

Comment: The source code you provided is a bit complicated. Although I could not refer to your method, I still found some simple methods while reading. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const extensionId = 'publisher.name';
const extension = vscode.extensions.getExtension(extensionId);
```

Get the src path after publishing